# Enter name and grades from user input to get average grade

Tags: java, user-input

I am working on a code where you have a students name and his grades and it prints his name total scores and his average scores. I want to make it more functional in allowing the user to input there name and scores and get all that info back. I may try to further this into a class average where it allows to input multiple individual names, scores, and average, print each one separately then showing the class average. This is a second thought though, as I **need to have user input of grades and names first**.

This is what I have so far. 
I have a separate class to make some things simpler.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int numOfQuizzes;
    private int totalScore;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int getTotalScore() {
        return totalScore;
    }
    public void addQuiz(int score) {
        totalScore = totalScore + score;
        numOfQuizzes++;
    }
    public double getAverageScore(){
        return totalScore/(double)numOfQuizzes;
    }
}
```

Then i have the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String name = nameInput.next();

    Student student = new Student(name);

    student.addQuiz(96);
    student.addQuiz(94);
    student.addQuiz(93);
    student.addQuiz(92);

    System.out.println("Students Name: " + student.getName());
    System.out.println("Total Quiz Scores: " + student.getTotalScore());
    System.out.println("Average Quiz Score: " + student.getAverageScore());
}
```

This is what it prints out currently:

```
What is your name? Tom
Students Name: Tom
Total Quiz Scores: 375
Average Quiz Score: 93.75
```

**UPDATE:
This is what i have done so far. i added a loop and trying to use my student class but it doesn't seem to work with the array.**

```
ArrayList<String> scores = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String name = nameInput.next();

    Scanner scoreInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your scores (q to quit): ");

        String q = scoreInput.nextLine();

        scores.add(q);

          if (q.equals("q")) {
              scores.remove("q");

       Student student = new Student(name);

       System.out.println("Students Name: " + student.getName());
       System.out.println("Total Quiz Scores: " + student.getTotalScore());
       System.out.println("Average Quiz Score: " + student.getAverageScore());
       break;
    }
   }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Have you learned about [control flow statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html) including loops yet?

Comment: "_I want to make it more functional in allowing the user to input there name and scores and get all that info back_" You are already getting the name from the user - what specific issue do you have with getting the scores too?

Comment: @csmckelveyI am trying to allow for multiple inputs of grades from the user till the user wants to stop.

Comment: @VasanI have but I don't have a great grasp on it. i understand if the user inputs some then this happens or else this does but don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only learning the language just yet, I'll give you a few suggestions to send you on your way. You might want to use a `while`-loop to consistently ask the user for a new grade until they've given you an empty line or something. You can reuse your scanner to read the new grades and they can be converted to integers using `Integer.parseInt`. Hopefully this'll allow you to write your code further, it's already looking great :).

**EDIT**

There are several points which can be improved upon in your edited code. The following shows some of them (using `import java.io.Console;`):

```
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

// Request the name
System.out.print("What is your name? ");
String name = inp.nextLine();

// Create the student object
Student student = new Student(name);

// Ask for the grades
System.out.print("Please enter your scores (q to quit): ");
String grade = inp.nextLine();

while (!grade.equals("q")) {
   // Convert the grade to an integer and pass it 
   student.addQuiz(Integer.parseInt(grade));

   // Request a new grade
   grade = inp.nextLine();
}

// Report the results
System.out.println("Students Name: " + student.getName());
System.out.println("Total Quiz Scores: " + student.getTotalScore());
System.out.println("Average Quiz Score: " + student.getAverageScore());
```

Comment: i created an arraylist and added a loop but my math doesnt seem to work now any help?

Comment: How'd you mean? What do you put in, and what do you get out?

Comment: I added an update to my question and you can now see it above. Thank you for the help. i know i need to call addQuiz somehow but it doesn't seem to be working with the array

Comment: i was told to "With each element of the array, parse it into an integer, then call addQuiz" but i dont know what that means?

Comment: You where creating a new student for each grade you added, instead of a single student with all of the given grades. This was because you created the student object _inside_ your loop.

Comment: i moved it out and it doesnt seem to change

Comment: it causes an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at finalReview.FinalReview.main(FinalReview.java:73)

Comment: Did you feed it an empty line? It currently has no checks for invalid input. That might be something for you to implement.

Comment: Oh, the first `read` for your name should probably be `readLine`. It currently causes the next call to `readLine` to read the remainder to the end of the line. You could also use the same system with `readInt` to read the grades all at a single line ;).

Comment: where is the read at? XD sorry i am confused than you for helping me so much

Comment: Ahum, it's late and not my common interface. I mean `nextLine` ('0v0).

Comment: Your good mate! XD that worked for the first and last one but not for the enter scores one. That ones has an error. it says The method nextLine() in the type Scanner is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: It shouldn't be given any arguments, so just remove the string.

Comment: Changed 'q' to "q" but now in my output, I get infinity for average.